# The partial derivatives of $(1+x^2+y^2-2x-2y-2xy)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y)=(1+x^2+y^2-2x-2y-2xy)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, and I want to prove that

\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial ^{m+n}}{\partial x^{m} \partial y^{n}} f (0,0)= (n+m)! \tbinom{n+m}{n}
\end{equation*}

Is this possible?

Comment: How about induction?

Comment: It seems not that easy to find out the exact form of $\frac{\partial ^{m+n}}{\partial x^m \partial y^n} f(x,y)$ by reduction.

Comment: I’ll try it when I’m free, but just to confirm, did you make a mistake in copying the sign of $2xy$ in the bracket? Or the sign of $2y$ or $2x$? It would be much much simpler if you did.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't mistake them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the multidimensional Taylor expansion about the origin, of a function of two variables, is given as (see e.g. here: [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylorreihe#Mehrdimensionale_Taylorreihe))

\begin{equation*}
f(x,y)  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n y^m}{n! m!} \frac{\partial ^{m+n}}{\partial x^{m} \partial y^{n}} f (0,0)
\end{equation*}

Now the conjecture holds, if we show that, for arbitrary but small $x,y$,
\begin{equation*}
(1+x^2+y^2-2x-2y-2xy)^{-\frac{1}{2}}  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n y^m}{n! m!} 
 (n+m)! \tbinom{n+m}{n}  \\
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} {x^n y^m} {\Large(}\tbinom{n+m}{n} {\Large)}^2
\end{equation*}

This is identical to

\begin{equation*}
1 = (1+x^2+y^2-2x-2y-2xy) \cdot {\Huge[} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} {x^n y^m} {\Large(}\tbinom{n+m}{n} {\Large)}^2  {\Huge]}^2
\end{equation*}

We need to show that all coefficients of terms $x^a y^b$ on the RHS vanish, other than for $1 = x^0 y^0$. The latter holds true. Further, manual inspection of the coefficients of $x$, $y$, $x^2$, $y^2$ and $xy$ gives that they vanish.

We shall therefore write $0$ on the LHS. The understanding is that we look for the vanishing of coefficients of all higher order terms other than those described above.

Let us write 
$$
1+x^2+y^2-2x-2y-2xy = (1-x-y)^2 - 4xy
$$
where for small $x,y$, $1-x-y > 0$. Then

\begin{equation*}
0 = {\Huge[} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (1-x-y) {x^n y^m} {\Large(}\tbinom{n+m}{n} {\Large)}^2  {\Huge]}^2 - 4 x y {\Huge[} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} {x^n y^m} {\Large(}\tbinom{n+m}{n} {\Large)}^2  {\Huge]}^2
\end{equation*}

Shifting indices in the first term gives (note the shift in the summation interval too)

\begin{equation*}
0 = {\Huge[} 1+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} {x^n y^m}{\Huge[} {\Large(}\tbinom{n+m}{n} {\Large)}^2 - {\Large(}\tbinom{n+m-1}{n-1} {\Large)}^2  - {\Large(}\tbinom{n+m-1}{n} {\Large)}^2  {\Huge]}{\Huge]}^2 \\
- 4 x y {\Huge[} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} {x^n y^m} {\Large(}\tbinom{n+m}{n} {\Large)}^2  {\Huge]}^2
\end{equation*}

The first term  can be simplified, so we get

\begin{equation*}
0 = {\Huge[} 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} {x^n y^m} \frac{2 m n }{(m+n)^2} {\Large(}\tbinom{n+m}{n} {\Large)}^2 {\Huge]}^2 - 4 x y {\Huge[} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} {x^n y^m} {\Large(}\tbinom{n+m}{n} {\Large)}^2  {\Huge]}^2
\end{equation*}

Now let us collect all terms which lead to a factor $x^a y^b$ with $a \ge 1, b \ge 1$.  After expanding the squared sums we obtain

\begin{equation*}
\frac{4 a b }{(a+b)^2} {\Large(}\tbinom{a+b}{a} {\Large)}^2   x^a y^b +
\\
+ \sum_{n=1}^{a}\sum_{m=1}^{b} \sum_{k=1, n+k = a}^{a}\sum_{l=1, m+l = b}^{b} {x^{n+k} y^{m+l}} \frac{4 m n k l  }{(m+n)^2(k+l)^2} {\Large(}\tbinom{n+m}{n} {\Large)}^2  {\Large(}\tbinom{k+l}{l} {\Large)}^2   
\\
- 4 x y 
 \sum_{n=0}^{a-1}\sum_{m=0}^{b-1} \sum_{k=0, n+k = a-1}^{a-1}\sum_{l=0, m+l = b-1}^{b-1} {x^{n+k} y^{m+l}}  {\Large(}\tbinom{n+m}{n} {\Large)}^2  {\Large(}\tbinom{k+l}{l} {\Large)}^2   
\end{equation*}

Replacing $k$ and $l$  with the equality constraints gives the *coefficients* $C(a,b)$ of all terms which lead to a factor $x^a y^b$

\begin{equation*}
C(a,b) = \frac{4 a b }{(a+b)^2} {\Large(}\tbinom{a+b}{a} {\Large)}^2   +
\\
+ \sum_{n=1}^{a}\sum_{m=1}^{b} \frac{4 m n (a-n)(b-m)  }{(m+n)^2(a-n+b-m)^2} {\Large(}\tbinom{n+m}{n} {\Large)}^2  {\Large(}\tbinom{a-n+b-m}{a-n} {\Large)}^2   
\\
- 4
 \sum_{n=0}^{a-1}\sum_{m=0}^{b-1}  {\Large(}\tbinom{n+m}{n} {\Large)}^2  {\Large(}\tbinom{a-1-n+b-1-m}{a-1-n} {\Large)}^2 
\end{equation*}

Shifting indices by one, for $n$ and $m$, in the last sum, gives

\begin{equation*}
C(a,b) = \frac{4 a b }{(a+b)^2} {\Large(}\tbinom{a+b}{a} {\Large)}^2   +\\
+ 4 \sum_{n=1}^{a}\sum_{m=1}^{b}  {\Huge[}\frac{ m (a-n)(b-m)  }{n(a-n+b-m)^2} {\Large(}\tbinom{n+m-1}{n-1} {\Large)}^2  -   {\Large(}\tbinom{n+m-2}{n-1} {\Large)}^2 {\Huge]} {\Large(}\tbinom{a-n+b-m}{a-n} {\Large)}^2 
\end{equation*}

In here, the fraction $\frac{ (a-n)(b-m)  }{(a-n+b-m)^2}$ is understood to be zero for $a=n$ and $b=m$.

Now as one can verify, $C(a,b)$ is indeed identically equal to zero for all $a$ and $b$.

So indeed, the coefficients of all terms other than $1$ vanish, as demanded. This completes the proof. $\qquad \Box$

Comment: Okay, thank you for such an ingenious proof. I'll read it carefully when I'm free. The last combinatorial identity seems complicated.

Comment: Yes, the last combinatorial identity is complicated. I checked it by computer, which showed correct values. I am still looking around for a formal verification  from credible sources.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different method which leads to a direct proof of the conjecture.

Write

\begin{equation*}
g(x,y) = 1+x^2+y^2-2x-2y-2xy
\end{equation*}

Now we have $ Q(x,y) = (f(x,y))^2 g(x,y) \equiv  1 $, i.e. this is an identity for all $(x,y)$. Therefore we can take arbitrary derivatives of this identity and obtain further identities. Denote 
$$
f^{(m,n)} = \frac{\partial ^{m+n}}{\partial x^{m} \partial y^{n}} f(x,y)\\
g_x = \frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial x} = 2x - 2 - 2y \quad ; g_y = \frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y} = 2y - 2 - 2x \\
g_{xx} = \frac{\partial^2 g(x,y)}{\partial x^2} = 2 \quad ; g_{yy} = \frac{\partial^2 g(x,y)}{\partial y^2} = 2\quad ; g_{xy} =g_{yx}  \frac{\partial^2 g(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y} = -2
$$
Note all further partial derivatives of $g$ are zero.

Now taking partial derivatives of the identity $Q$ gives (with the same index notation):

$$
Q_x = 2 f f^{(1,0)} g + f^2 g_x = 0 \quad {\rm{or}} \quad Q'_x = 2 f^{(1,0)} g + f g_x = 0 \\
 Q'_{xx} = 2 f^{(2,0)} g + 3 f^{(1,0)} g_x+ f g_{xx} = 0 \\
 Q'_{x^3} = 2 f^{(3,0)} g + 5 f^{(2,0)} g_x+ 4 f^{(1,0)} g_{xx} = 0 \\
$$
In the last line, no further derivatives of $g$ need to be included since they are all zero, as seen above.

Iterating the above process gives

$$
 Q'_{x^m} = 2 f^{(m,0)} g + (2m -1) f^{(m-1,0)} g_x+ (m-1)^2 f^{(m-2,0)} g_{xx} = 0 \\
$$

Now continue with partial derivatives w.r.t. $y$. We do this for the three terms separatately. The method works in the same fashion as laid out with the partial $x$-derivatives.

$$
\frac{\partial ^{n}}{\partial y^{n}}  (f^{(m,0)} g) =  f^{(m,n)} g + n f^{(m,n-1)} g_y + \frac12 n(n-1) f^{(m,n-2)} g_{yy} \\
\frac{\partial ^{n}}{\partial y^{n}}  (f^{(m-1,0)} g_x) =  f^{(m-1,n)} g_x + n f^{(m-1,n-1)} g_{xy} \\
\frac{\partial ^{n}}{\partial y^{n}}  (f^{(m-2,0)} g_{xx}) =  f^{(m-2,n)} g_{xx} \\
$$

So we can insert these results and get

$$
 Q'_{x^m y^n} = 2 f^{(m,n)} g + 2 n f^{(m,n-1)} g_y +  n(n-1) f^{(m,n-2)} g_{yy} \\
+ (2m -1) f^{(m-1,n)} g_x + (2m -1) n f^{(m-1,n-1)} g_{xy} + (m-1)^2 f^{(m-2,n)} g_{xx}  = 0 
$$

Now we insert the values for $g$ and the partial derivatives of $g$ at $x=y=0$. We obtain 
$$
 f^{(m,n)} - 2 n f^{(m,n-1)}  +  n(n-1) f^{(m,n-2)} 
- (2m -1) f^{(m-1,n)} - (2m -1) n f^{(m-1,n-1)}  + (m-1)^2 f^{(m-2,n)}  = 0 
$$
where all values of $ f^{(a,b)} $ are now, and further on, understood to be taken at $(0,0)$. This is the condition for $ f^{(a,b)} $ which has to be obeyed for all $(a,b)$, and the initial conditions have to be met.

Since the conjecture gives us

\begin{equation*}
 f^{(m,n)}  = \frac{\partial ^{m+n}}{\partial x^{m} \partial y^{n}} f (0,0)= (n+m)! \tbinom{n+m}{n}
\end{equation*}
it now remains to prove that this indeed satisfies the condition. Inserting, and extracting $ f^{(m,n)}  $, gives

$$
 1- 2 n \frac{n}{(n+m)^2} +  n(n-1) \frac{n(n-1)}{(n+m)^2(n+m-1)^2} 
- (2m -1) \frac{m}{(n+m)^2}  - (2m -1) n \frac{n m}{(n+m)^2(n+m-1)^2}  + (m-1)^2 \frac{m(m-1)}{(n+m)^2(n+m-1)^2}  = 0 
$$
which must be valid for all $n\ge2$, $m \ge 2$. Now, it is simply some laborious algebra to show that the LHS is indeed identically zero.

The cases $n<2$, $m < 2$ are easily checked manually for the original conjecture.

This completes the proof. $\qquad \Box$